# In Lua, is there a difference between local functions declared with and without the "local" keyword?

Tags: lua, scope

Preface: As far as I can see, the docs on the website don't really speak to this, and I haven't found anyone else even *asking* the question, so I'm pretty sure these two forms are identical, but I want know if anyone knows *for certain*.

Given this Lua code:

```
function f()
    function a() ... end
    local function b() ... end
    ...
end
```

Is there any functional difference between `a()` and `b()`? I'm speaking in terms of performance, access, caveats, anything at all. Like, in the end, do they both have exactly the same underlying representation at runtime?

I suspect there isn't any difference, but I'm not *sure*, and that bugs me. I know `a()` is *scoped* to the enclosing function `f()`, but I'm not sure if that truly makes it a local variable in terms of how things function under the hood. With `b()`, I can be certain.

We know from the official docs that my definition of `b()` above is syntactic sugar for this:

```
    local b
    b = function() ... end
```

I'm tempted to believe that, even without the `local` keyword in *my* definition, the final, de-sugared definition of `a()` would also follow exactly that format, including the `local a` part.

I just feel like I can't *assume* this.

Comment: To clear up a few points: 1) functions are values; only variables are local or global. 2) a function has a definition expression (or equivalent statement) that creates a function value when executed, not a declaration. 3) f or a could be local unless you've shown the entire code in the compiled chunk. 4) a is not scoped to the enclosing block.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`function a() end` in your code block assigns global `a` when the function is ran*, while `b` remains local to the function.

Perhaps this code segment will illustrate things better:

```
function f()
    function a() end
    local function b() end
end
print(a, b) -- nil, nil
f()
print(a, b) -- function: 0xdeadbeef, nil
```

So to avoid polluting the global environment, you should still use `local` inside of a function.

---

* Unless you declared `a` local at some other scope above `f`, in which case `a` will keep its scoping.

Comment: `a` may be not a global.  It may be an upvalue.

Comment: Ah, wow, the assumption was so strong that I didn't even think to see if a global had been set when the function ran. Calling a() from global space even preserves any upvalues that were given to f() and used in a(), because of *course* it does. Cheers, this definitely answers the question, and it's nice to see behavior is actually consistent. :)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - Ah, you mean if 'a' already existed in an enclosing function? I suppose that's true. Good point.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer to your question, but the most accessible look under the hood of Lua is [here](https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf) written by the creator of Lua. There is some discussion of local variables, but I don't think it answers your question exactly. The section on "external locals" versus explicitly declared locals is informative.

EDIT:
And [here](https://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf) too. I'll have to read this one again to see if it answers your question. If you beat me to it, do share what you learn!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance local functions are faster than global ones. In large code-bases, a common `lua` optimization trick is to "cache" a globally defined function in a local reference and use the latter. In code:

```
--file_A.lua
function performAnExpensiveComputation()
...
end
```

And in the file where you actually want to use this function:

```
--file_B.lua
require "file_A.lua"

local performAnExpensiveComputation = performAnExpensiveComputation 

local result = performAnExpensiveComputation() --You are now using the locally referenced function
```

This is just a variation of the technique used to [optimize](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OptimisingUsingLocalVariables) `lua` variables.

Comment: This really isn't answering the question I asked.

Comment: If you think my answer is not helpful I will retract it. But, with regards to performance, my post answers what you are describing in the title "is there a difference between local functions declared with and without the “local” keyword?"

Comment: This applies to variables, regardless of the type of value they hold at any particular time.

Comment: @TomBlodget - I realize your answer was well-intentioned and *does* discuss one of the differences that would come up IF the two definitions were different. But, the main thrust of my question was about whether or not the two definitions would differ, since local functions are implicitly local to begin with. They *do* differ, as noted in the accepted answer, but simply telling me how a local and global function differ in perf is an answer for a simpler question about whether it's worth it to cache functions in local vars, and I'm sure that question has been asked and answered many times on SE.

Comment: @AikenDrum You seem to be mistaking me for the answer author. However, responding to your incidental points, you seem to be importing the concept of a "local function" from another programming language. "local functions are implicitly local" is not true. Again, functions are values. Only variables can be local and the only implicit locals are parameters.

Comment: @TomBlodget - Oops, sorry. You're right, I didn't notice the name mismatch. And yes, I get that functions are values. I was explaining how the question came about, not necessarily what the correct answer looked like. Questions tend to arise out of ignorance, remember. Knowing the answer now doesn't make me less ignorant back when I asked the question. :) As an aside, there IS a difference between local and global functions, even as values, because global functions are not closures.

Comment: @AikenDrum (myself) - I just realized that I stated something in my previous comment that isn't entirely true: "global functions are not closures". While they normally aren't, they actually _can_ be, as I noted in a comment on the accepted answer, where I discovered that if the function you create inside another function is not marked local, but uses local values, it will indeed have upvalues from that function, so it _would_ be a closure. Which is kind of amazing, but also an invisible gun aimed at your foot if you miss a "local" prefix inside of a function acting as a function factory.